# ASP.NET - Enter disabled on form prevents enter (new line) in multiline textbox

Tags: asp.net, forms, textbox, enter, onkeypress

I have a master page with a form:

```
<form id="FormMaster" runat="server" onkeypress="return (event.keyCode != 13)">
```

The enter  key disabled is a must. However, now the enter key is disabled in textboxes as well, and that is a problem.

Is there a way I can enable enter key for textboxes inside this form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply *don't* disable "form enter" using the form keypress event.

If there is more than one input/control, browsers shouldn't "submit on enter", but rather only when enter is pressed *while* a submit button is focused .. (which means you can use a similar approach to disable enter on the submit button or make it unfocusable in such cases).

If you *must* use the keypress event of the form, look at the [*Event Target*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target) property, and only perform the event suppression if not one of the appropriate multi-line inputs (aka textarea elements).

```
if ((event.target || event.srcElement).nodeName != "TEXTAREA") {
   // not textarea (multi-line input), suppress as original
}
```

Comment: Yes, the keypress seriously is a must, someone else decides that, I just write code :-/ However - your solution works perfectly. Thanks!